# How to pass Get params when using firebase functions call

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function that retrieves some Get params when triggered:

```js
  const developerId: string = request.query.developerId;
  const appPackage: string = request.query.appPackage;
```

As you see, I get the get params using request.query.

When using cloud functions emulator it is more confortable for me to trigger functions through command line with a call like that:

```
functions call registerInstall --file=.\function_params\registerInstall.json
```

registerInstall.json is just a file that contains the parameters passed to the registerInstall function when called from the command line.

The problem I'm getting is that I get these parameters through the request.body member instead of request.query that is the correct one when triggering the function using any web browser.

Is there any possibility to force the "functions call" to pass the params in the .json file through the request.query member instead of request.body?

Cheers.